# What is this stuff at the bottom of my brine tank?

Tags: water-softener

[image]

There is this brown silt/sediment on the salt pellets at the bottom of my brine tank.  What is that?

Comment: Added image to compare to comment.  Is this the same stuff (iron oxide)?

Answer (score 2):

Usually a brown color discoloration in a water system, such as a softener unit, is due to iron. Iron combines with oxygen to form iron oxide which is reddish brown in color.

You may be more familiar with rust on metal parts made of iron. Rust is simply iron oxide.

Comment: The iron comes in as ferrous ions, slightly water soluble. In your system , it gets oxidized to ferric ; settling  out as Fe 2 O 3 , red rust/ iron oxide  which is insoluble.